# CIVIEVENT warning messages for free events with no payment processor

Tags: civievent, payment

CIVICRM 5.67.0 Wordpress 6.4.2 PHP 8.2
I am getting lots of warning messages along these lines

"Warning: Undefined array key "participant_fee_level" in /homepages/46/d4297868751/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%FE/FEB/FEB92208%%Selector.tpl.php on line 21
(no fee)"

"Warning: Undefined array key "participant_fee_amount" in /homepages/46/d4297868751/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%FE/FEB/FEB92208%%Selector.tpl.php on line 21"

.... and similar.

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to avoid.

Comment: While civi "works" with php 8, it does have a ton of these notices. Until they're all fixed you can set error_reporting = 1 in your php.ini. That doesn't "fix" them, it just hides the warnings.